# Embedding problems on quantum groups？

Tags: lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

We work over the field of complex numbers.
We have known that Lie algebra of type $A_2 $is a subalgebra of type $G_2$. However, when we consider their quantum groups, is  this true i.e. does there exist $p,q$ such that $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}(3))$ is a subalgebra of $U_p(\mathfrak{g})$ as associative algebra, where $\mathfrak{g}= G_2$?

Comment: Since this algebra  also have a coalgebra structure, and I just need to consider it as an algebra.

Comment: Since they are given by generators and relations, why not just to check the relations for $U_q(sl(3))$ on "long root" generators of $U_p({\mathfrak g})$? Or do you need a more "functorial" answer for further applications?